# Which approach to building domain objects in Spring MVC is more correct?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have three domain classes which need to be persisted:

```
class House{
    private List<Room> rooms;
    private Address address;
}

class Room{
    private String id;
    ...
}

class Address{
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

1. Shall domain objects have id fields?
2. If yes, what is better: to realize House class like it's done in the top of question or replace object fields with lighter `String`s containing ids?

   class House{
       private List<'String> roomIds;
       private String addressId;
   }

Thank you!

Comment: don't use strings as references. use objects e.g. `Room`, `Address` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each domain object should have ID, because you must provide uniqueness of each entity in database. Type of Id field depends on database which you use. If you use sql database then it is usually long type. If you use MongoDb - it is String.

> class House{ private List<'String> roomIds; private String addressId; }

You shouldn't use list of Ids. It is bad practice. Use relationships between entities instead. Сonsider using JPA for building domain model. In your case relation between house and room - OneToMany, because a particular house can include a lot of rooms but each room can belong to only one house. In case of Address...this is OneToOne relation. Each address has single house(flat). You can use Address as embeddable object into House.

```
class House{
  private long houseId;
  private List<Room> rooms;
  private Address address;
}

class Room{
  private int roomId;
  private House house;
}

class Address{
  private long addressId;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each class should have an id and you need to annotate using **@Id** if your using hibernate. When designing your model you should consider two type of keys.

**Natural Key** -
A natural key (also known as business key) is a type of unique key, found in relational model database design, that is formed of attributes that already exist in the real world. It is used in business-related columns. ... A natural key is sometimes called domain key.

**Surrogate Key** - A surrogate key is any column or set of columns that can be declared as the primary key instead of a "real" or natural key. Sometimes there can be several natural keys.